# Need guidance converting WPF C# code behind to MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

My objective here is to get assistance converting this simple WPF sample with code behind to MVVM, which will help me greatly in understanding how to take what I want to do in the future and write up the MVVM for it.

I have a blind spot when it comes to learning MVVM.  Ideally, I'd like a copy of the entire files (just as I have done in the below sample) so it's ready for me to plug in and tinker with it.  Suggestions like "put this snippet in your ViewModel" aren't helpful to me because building the ViewModel, as a whole, is part of the ask.

I wouldn't ask for this type of help if I hadn't already spent too much time trying to learn using online tutorials that aren't relative to my immediate needs.  I appreciate the assistance!

In this example, the user selects one of three RadioButtons.  Depending on the RadioButton checked, the TextBlock and Label display the appropriate string.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="VMTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VMTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbRed" Content="Red Means Stop" Checked="RbRed_Checked"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbYellow" Content="Yellow Means Go Faster" Checked="RbYellow_Checked"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbGreen" Content="Green Mean Go" Checked="RbGreen_Checked"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="myLabel" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace VMTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly string LabelString1 = "1234567890";
        private readonly string LabelString2 = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
        private readonly string LabelString3 = "abcdefghij";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RbRed_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myTextBlock.Text = rbRed.Content.ToString();
            myLabel.Content = LabelString1;
        }

        private void RbYellow_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myTextBlock.Text = rbYellow.Content.ToString();
            myLabel.Content = LabelString2;
        }

        private void RbGreen_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myTextBlock.Text = rbGreen.Content.ToString();
            myLabel.Content = LabelString3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package:

   ```
    Install-Package CommunityToolkit.Mvvm
   ```

   It's a MVVM Toolkit that is maintained and published by Microsoft and it gives you a collection of standard, self-contained, lightweight types that provide a starting implementation for building modern apps using the MVVM pattern. An example of such a type is the `RelayCommand<T>` class which implements the `ICommand` interface. Another example is the `ObservableObject` base class which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
2. Get rid of the event handlers in the view and replace them with a binding to an `ICommand` property. Also bind the `TextBlock` to a `string` property:

   ```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton Content="Red Means Stop" Command="{Binding SelectColorCommand}" CommandParameter="red" GroupName="color"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Yellow Means Go Faster" Command="{Binding SelectColorCommand}" CommandParameter="yellow" GroupName="color"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Green Mean Go" Command="{Binding SelectColorCommand}" CommandParameter="green" GroupName="color"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Label}"/>
    </Grid>
   ```
3. Create the view model which sets the data-bound `Label` property when the command is executed:

   ```
    public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly string LabelString1 = "1234567890";
        private readonly string LabelString2 = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
        private readonly string LabelString3 = "abcdefghij";

        public ViewModel()
        {
            SelectColorCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(SelectColor);
        }

        public RelayCommand<object> SelectColorCommand { get; }

        private void SelectColor(object parameter)
        {
            string color = parameter?.ToString();
            switch (color)
            {
                case "red":
                    Label = LabelString1;
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    Label = LabelString2;
                    break;
                case "green":
                    Label = LabelString3;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private string _label;
        public string Label
        {
            get { return _label; }
            set { _label = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Label)); }
        }
    }
   ```

   The `CommandParameter` is used to determine which `RadioButton` that was checked.
4. Set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of the view model:

   ```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!